# Windows Inaccessible_boot_device after dual boot

Tags: arch-linux, windows, dual-boot

I wanted to do a UEFI dual boot with Arch Linux and Windows 10 on a 1TB GPT SSD. I read [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dual_boot_with_Windows) and decided follow the 'Linux before Windows' installation (I already had a working Arch Linux install on another SSD). However, after installing windows, I got the infamous "Inaccessible_boot_device" screen. I am not using RAID, nor do I have a controller for it.

These were my steps:

1. I partitioned the space as follows (output from `fdisk -l`):

   ```
   bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size
   (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disklabel type: gpt Disk
   identifier: 05E9711B-29A2-4D4F-9E40-812D4F57DF4E

   Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type 
   /dev/sda1        2048     2099199   2097152    1G EFI System 
   /dev/sda2     2099200    35653631  33554432   16G Linux swap 
   /dev/sda3    35653632  304089087  268435456  128G Linux filesystem 
   /dev/sda4   304089088  534775807  230686720  110G Linux home 
   /dev/sda5   534775808 1071646719  536870912  256G Linux filesystem 
   /dev/sda7  1281361920 1281394687      32768   16M Microsoft reserved 
   /dev/sda8  1281394688 1282478079    1083392  529M Windows recovery environment 
   /dev/sda9  1282478080 1911623679  629145600  300G Microsoft basic data
   ```
2. I used `rsync` to copy my arch files from one partition
   to another, excluding the EFI partition. I then installed GRUB to
   check if I could boot into linux and all went ok.
3. I installed windows using the latest version of windows, using
   a removable medium. I chose 'Advanced Setup' and I installed it on
   the Windows Basic Data partition (`/dev/sda9` in my case)
4. I booted into arch linux and reconfigured GRUB using `os-prober` and
   it successfully chainloaded the Windows Boot Manager.
5. Booted into windows and got the blue screen with the Inaccessible_boot_device error. Linux works just fine.

What I have tried:

- Repairing the windows install through the installation media ("Automatic repair")
- Reinstalling windows
- Using BCDedit to modify the default boot option (my hunch was that the bootloader did not know / could not find the windows partition) -- from the output of `bcdedit` the right partition is selected as default
- Checking the volume for errors using `chkdsk`
- Using BCDedit to modify a lot of other fields, none of them yielding any results

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. That means Windows fast start up must be off. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation  If UEFI install, you should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI, and maybe f8 into its internal repair console to turn off fast start up or make other fixes.

Comment: Hi @oldfred. My GRUB is successfully chainloading the windows boot manager. I know this because the windows logo, alongside the loading circle is appearing. As you said, I am able to boot windows without GRUB.
However, safe mode and any other f8 option is yielding the same result (the error). I cannot disable the fast start up as I am unable to boot into the system. Is there any way to achieve this without booting into Windows?

Comment: I do not think so. And if you cannot start Windows that would be a Windows issue. Perhaps from your repair/recovery flash drive or install drive, run the full set of Windows repairs. Be sure to boot repair in UEFI mode, so it repairs in UEFI mode. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156795/windows-hard-disk-read-only-now-windows-is-removed?noredirect=1#comment1925839_1156795